# Incorrect "Mailbox Store" in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I recently had to restore our primary domain controller from a backup, but the backup was taken *before* a mailbox was moved (from mail1 to mail2). The user now has the problem that they cannot access their email. This appears to be because Outlook is looking for the emails on mail1.domain.com, whereas the actual emails are on mail2.domain.com.

In AD, the users "Mailbox Store" attribute is set to "MAIL1/First Storage Group/Mailbox Store (MAIL1)".

In event viewer on MAIl1 (which is also our PDC), the following event is logged :

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   MSExchangeIS Mailbox Store
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   1205
Date:       26/10/2009
Time:       09:30:49
User:       N/A
Computer:   MAIL1
Description:
Failed to create the mailbox of 
/o=DOMAIN/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=<user> with error 0x50c.
```

How can I tell AD where the mailbox is correctly located?

Comment: There are no "primary domain controller" or "PDC" computers in Active Directory. There are only "domain controllers" some of which might hold unique FSMO roles. Otherwise, they're all the same. None is "primary".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed the problem with [this article](http://exchangepedia.com/blog/2006/03/how-to-reconnect-mailbox-to-another.html).